# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects list contains integer

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I want my output to be:

```
"fileselection":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

My code:

```
li=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
st='"fileselection":'
print st+",".join(li)
```

It is currently complaining:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just calling `str()` on the list makes the output you want:

```
>>> li = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> st = '"fileselection":'
>>> st + str(li)
'"fileselection":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]'
```

---

The problem you see is because the elements of `li` are integers, for joining them to a string you need first to cast them to `str`. You can do this by applying `str()` function via `map()`:

```
>>> st + ','.join(map(str, li))
'"fileselection":0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
```